# Select variable only if exists SAS SQL

Tags: sql, variables, sas, exists

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE SET3 AS 
    SELECT 
        a.VAR1 , b.VAR1 AS P_VAR1 , 
        a.VAR2          
    FROM SET1 AS a FULL JOIN SET2 AS B
    ON  a.VAR1 = b.VAR1 
 ;
QUIT;
```

The code above creates a table called SET3 and includes VAR1 from 2 datasets, along with VAR2 where a.VAR1=b.VAR1.

I want this code to run to include VAR2 ***if it is available***. It is sometimes not and so the code crashes.

I could do this by writing the code twice with some macros but was wondering if there was a quick, SQL syntax which could be used.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create a macro variable that will either have VAR1 or VAR1,VAR2 depending on whether it exists.  `dictionary.columns` is the metadata table you can get this from, which is available in `proc sql`.

The order of the final data will be slightly different (a.VAR1, a.VAR2, b.VAR1), but hopefully that won't be an issue.

```
proc sql noprint;
select cats('a.',name) into :varlist separated by ','
from dictionary.columns
where libname='WORK' and memname='SET1' and name in ('VAR1','VAR2');
quit;

%put &=varlist.;

PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE SET3 AS 
    SELECT 
        &varlist. , b.VAR1 AS P_VAR1
    FROM SET1 AS a FULL JOIN SET2 AS B
    ON  a.VAR1 = b.VAR1 
 ;
QUIT;
```

Comment: Please, this line is for what? %put &=varlist.; or do you mean : %put &varlist.;

Comment: It just puts the values of &varlist. into the log.  `%put &=varlist.` is a shortcut way of coding `%put VARLIST=&varlist.`

Comment: OK! Thank you for this explanation.